# Read tails bytes from a binary file in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is my attempt:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//  Forward declarations:
void append(LPCTSTR, LPCVOID, DWORD);
void readTail(LPCTSTR, LPVOID, DWORD);


int main()
{
    LPCTSTR fn = L"C:/kaiyin/kybig.out";
    LPCVOID buf = "eeeee"; 
    append(fn, buf, 5);
    LPVOID buf1 = ""; 
    readTail(fn, buf1, 5);
    std::cout << (char*) buf1 << std::endl;


    printf("hello world\n");
    std::string s = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    return 0;
}

void append(LPCTSTR filename, LPCVOID buf, DWORD writeSize) {
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    WriteFile(fh, buf, writeSize, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(fh);
}

void readTail(LPCTSTR filename, LPVOID buf, DWORD readSize) {
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    size.QuadPart -= readSize;
    SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(fh, buf, readSize, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(fh);
}
```

The `append` function seems to increase the file size by the correct number (5 bytes), but printing the last 5 byte to in the console doesn't show anything. 
What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not allocated buffer for your result:

```
LPVOID buf1 = ""; 
readTail(fn, buf1, 5);
```

`buf1` is only a pointer to empty string, what you want is some buffer where to put your results:

```
BYTE buf1[10] = { 0 };
readTail(fn, buf1, 5);
```

Also, you are appending initialy to existing file (due to OPEN_EXISTING),so makesure you have an empty `C:/kaiyin/kybig.out` file.

Comment: Appending to an existing file is my intention. Or perhaps I misunderstood something? I thought I need the `OPEN_EXISTING ` flag.

Comment: @qed thats fine, just dont forget to check for invalid handle ie.: `fh` will be equal to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in such case, and `GetLastError` will   contain appropriate error code.

Comment: You mean something like this? `if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  std::cerr << GetLastError();
  return;
 }`

Comment: @qed yes, nearly all WinAPI functions might fail, SetFilePointerEx also returns FALSE in such case and appropriate error is in GetLastError()

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here is the modified code according to suggestions from @marcinj :

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//  Forward declarations:
void append(LPCTSTR, LPCVOID, DWORD);
void readTail(LPCTSTR, LPVOID, DWORD);
void truncateTail(LPCTSTR, long);


int main()
{
    LPCTSTR fn = L"C:/kaiyin/kybig.out";
    char buf[] = "helloWorld"; 
    append(fn, buf, 10);
    BYTE buf1[10] = {0};
    readTail(fn, buf1, 5);
    std::cout << (char*) buf1 << std::endl;
    truncateTail(fn, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buf1[i] = 0;
    }
    readTail(fn, buf1, 5);
    std::cout << (char*) buf1 << std::endl;

    printf("End of program\n");
    std::string s = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    return 0;
}

void append(LPCTSTR filename, LPCVOID buf, DWORD writeSize) {
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    WriteFile(fh, buf, writeSize, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(fh);
}

void readTail(LPCTSTR filename, LPVOID buf, DWORD readSize) {
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    size.QuadPart -= readSize;
    SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    ReadFile(fh, buf, readSize, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(fh);
}

void truncateTail(LPCTSTR filename, long truncateSize) {
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE fh = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (fh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << GetLastError();
        return;
    }
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    size.QuadPart -= truncateSize;
    SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN); 
    if (SetEndOfFile(fh) == 0) {
        std::cerr << GetLastError();
        return;
    }
    CloseHandle(fh);
}
```